# Find first available file to output log to

Tags: powershell

I am working on a complete rewrite of my logging function that I use for a couple hundred scripts and I am trying to make it as robust as possible. I am trying to make it be able to create go through a very basic set of checks to find the first available log that it can write to.

I am trying to write it so it will attempt to write to each log file (in case the files have different permisisons than the directories)

Logic path

- Go through each directory in the list
- See if there are any logs I can append to
- If there is append to them
- If not, try to create a new log with `#` appended to it.
- If cannot create a new log, move on to the next directory

This script isn't very difficult, I've written much more complex scripts, but for some reason my brain will not wrap its head around this and I keep coming up with non-robust very repetetive functions and I am trying to keep effiency and speed as the most important priority.

```cs
Function TestLogger {
    $WriteTee = @{}
    $WriteTee.LogName  = 'WriteTee.log'
    #$WriteTee.LogName  = "$(((Split-Path -Leaf $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)).BaseName).txt"
    $WriteTee.LogPaths = "C:\Windows\",
                         'C:\Users\1151577373E\Documents\Powershell Scripts\AutoUpdater\',
                         "$Env:UserProfile"
                         #"$(Split-Path -Parent $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"

    foreach ($Path in $WriteTee.LogPaths) {
        $Path = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Path
        #Ensure the directory exists and if not, create it.
        if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($Path)) {
            try {
                New-Item -Path $Path.Parent.FullName -Name $Path.BaseName -ItemType 'Directory' -ErrorAction Stop -Force | Out-Null
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }

        #Check to see if there are any existing logs
        $WriteTee.ExistingLogs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Filter "$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).BaseName)*$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).Extension)" |Sort-Object
        if ($WriteTee.ExistingLogs.Count -eq 0) {
            $WriteTee.LastLogName = $null
        } else {
            foreach ($ExistingLog in $WriteTee.ExistingLogs) {
                try {
                    [IO.File]::OpenWrite($ExistingLog.FullName).close() | Out-Null
                    $WriteTee.LogFile = $ExistingLog.FullName
                    break
                } catch {
                    $WriteTee.LastLogName = $ExistingLog
                    continue
                }
            }
        }

        #If no previous logs can be added to create a new one.
        if (-not $WriteTee.ContainsKey('LogFile')) {
            switch ($WriteTee.LastLogName.Name) {
                {$_ -eq $Null} {
                    $WriteTee.ExistingLogs.count
                    Write-Host Create New File
                }
                {$_ -match '.*\[[0-9]+\]\.'} {
                    Write-Host AAAAAA
                    $WriteTee.NextLogName = $WriteTee.NextLogName.FullName.Split('[]')
                    $WriteTee.NextLogName = $WriteTee.NextLogName[0] + "[" + ([int]($WriteTee.NextLogName[1]) + 1) + "]" + $WriteTee.NextLogName[2]
                }
                default {}
            }
        }

        #Determine if log file is available or not.
        if ($WriteTee.ContainsKey('LogFile')) {
            Write-Host "Function Success"
            break
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    return $WriteTee.LogFile
}
clear
TestLogger
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] and a problem decription this sounds better suited in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I just burnt myself out yesturday, good night sleep got me going again. here is what I ended up with, really hope someone else finds some use out of it.

```
Function TestLogger {
    $WriteTee = @{}
    $WriteTee.LogName  = 'WriteTee.log'
    #$WriteTee.LogName  = "$(((split-path -leaf $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)).BaseName).Log"
    $WriteTee.LogPaths = 'C:\Windows\',
                         "C:\Users\1151577373E\Documents\Powershell Scripts\AutoUpdater\",
                         "$Env:UserProfile"
                         #"$(split-path -parent $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"


    Foreach ($Path in $WriteTee.LogPaths) {
        If ($WriteTee.ContainsKey('LogFile')) { Break }
        $Path = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Path
        #Ensure the directory exists and if not, create it.
        If (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($Path)) {
            Try {
                #Create the directory because .Net will error out if you try to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist yet.
                New-Item -Path $Path.Parent.FullName -Name $Path.BaseName -ItemType 'Directory' -ErrorAction Stop -Force |Out-Null
            } Catch {
                Continue
            }
        }#End-If

        #Check to see if there are any existing logs
        $WriteTee.ExistingLogs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Filter "$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).BaseName)*$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).Extension)" |Sort-Object
        If ($WriteTee.ExistingLogs.Count -GT 0) {
            ForEach ($ExistingLog in $WriteTee.ExistingLogs) {
                Try {
                    [io.file]::OpenWrite($ExistingLog.FullName).close() |Out-Null
                    $WriteTee.LogFile = $ExistingLog.FullName
                    break
                } Catch {
                    $WriteTee.LastLogName = $ExistingLog
                    Continue
                }
            }
        }#End-If

        #If no previous logs can be added to create a new one.
        switch ($WriteTee.ExistingLogs.Count) {
            {$PSItem -EQ 0} {
                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $WriteTee.LogName
            }
            {$PSItem -EQ 1} {
                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath ($WriteTee.LastLogName.basename + '[0]' + $WriteTee.LastLogName.Extension)
            }

            {$PSItem -GE 2} {
                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = $WriteTee.LastLogName.FullName.Split('[]')
                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = ($WriteTee.TestLogFile[0] + '[' + (([int]$WriteTee.TestLogFile[1]) + 1) + ']' + $WriteTee.TestLogFile[2])
            }
            Default {
                Write-Host "If you are looking for an explanation of how you got here, I can tell you I don't have one. But what I do have are a very particular lack of answers that I have aquired over a very long career that make these problems a nightmare for people like me."
                Continue
                }
        }#End-Switch

        #Last but not least, try to create the file and hope it is successful.
        Try {
            [IO.File]::Create($WriteTee.TestLogFile, 1, 'None').close() |Out-Null
            $WriteTee.LogFile = $WriteTee.TestLogFile
            Break
        } Catch {
            Continue
        }
    }#End-ForEach
    Return $WriteTee.LogFile

}
```